# Firestore using Firebase Client SDK V9 Modular with Admin Privileges

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Previously, all of my firestore query are using v8 namespaced.

All transactions are having full privileges using **Firebase Admin SDK** on my server.

I want to update the v8 namespaced to v9 modular syntax:

```
// from this
db.collection("cities").where("capital", "==", true).get();

// to this
const q = query(collection(db, "cities"), where("capital", "==", true));
```

Using **Firebase Client SDK v9**, it works when I force the *Database Rules* to `true`, without doing so I got error `permission-denied`.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebasev9 = initializeApp(configv9);

const db = getFirestore(firebasev9);

const q = query(collection(db, "cities"), where("capital", "==", true));
```

**Firebase Admin SDK v10** now have modular export similar as client sdk, so I tried it:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';

const firebaseAdminv9 = initializeApp(configAdminv9);

const db = getFirestore(firebaseAdminv9);

const q = query(collection(db, "cities"), where("capital", "==", true));
```

Now the error is `Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore`.

Seems like we cannot use the instance of `getFirestore` from `firebase-admin`.

Is there any way for the client sdk to have admin privilege?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  The client SDK cannot be initialized with a service account, which is the thing that's required for privileged access that bypasses security rules.  The client SDK only passes along the currently signed in user from Firebase Auth for authorization.

Furthermore, it is not possible at all mix usage of the client and admin SDKs.  Even though they have APIs that look similar, they are just not compatible with each other at all.

Comment: does that mean we can only wait for admin sdk to have the same modular methods as in client sdk ?

eg: ```import { collection, query, where } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';```

Comment: No, it already does in v10.  That was the main point of that release.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/migrate-node-v10

Comment: @DougStevenson You might have misunderstood the OP's question (or it might have been me?): firebase-adming v10 did not introduce what they are looking for - module entry points are modular, in some way, but within the Firestore module you cannot import the methods indvidually, they are going to be methods of the whole Firestore instance, like in v8 of Firestore, so this is certainly still missing, if it's in the pipeline at all for firebase-admin.

Comment: Basically we still have to develop v8-style of Firestore in firebase-admin...

Comment: I have lot of code which was sharable now it was done with 2 diff approaches (((