# authenticated firebase/firestore queries

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm very confused about how to send authenticated firebase/firestore calls.
I initialized firestore in my web app as below: (using Next.js)

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { GoogleAuthProvider, getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// firestore
export const db = getFirestore(app);

//auth
export const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
export const auth = getAuth();
```

One of my API:

```
import { db } from "../../../utils/db/init";
import {
  collection,
  addDoc,
  serverTimestamp,
  setDoc,
  doc,
} from "firebase/firestore";

/** [POST] Add user to database.
 * req.body requires:
 * @param email
 * @returns user
 */
export default async function addUserHandler(req, res) {
  try {
    const data = {
      ...req.body,
      createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
      followers: [],
      following: [],
    };
    const { id } = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), data);
    await setDoc(doc(db, "users", id), { seed: id }, { merge: true }); // add seed for sorting posts (same as id)

    res.status(200).json({ ...data, id }); 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json(error.message);
  }
}
```

In my firestore rules:

```
...
match /users/{userId}{
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

The user is logged in when this API is called, but firebase still says `Missing or insufficient permissions` when I call the API. Am I missing anything? How do I add the auth to the request?

Comment: In GCP, does the user that is making the API calls have the necessary permissions in IAM for the project? https://cloud.google.com/iam

Comment: I didn't really set up anything in IAM (it has firebase-adminsdk, Firebase Service Management Service Agent, and the owner emails in the permissions), I only downloaded the firebaseConfig from the console. Is there any additional setup I need to do? The user making the requests should be users who logged into my web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firebase client sdk should be used in the **client**, hence why you are getting `Missing or insufficient permissions` because security rules don't work in the server, as the server is meant to be a **trusted environment**.

To interact with the firebase sdk in the server, you should use the [firebase admin sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

Comment: I see, so if I'm writing API in nextjs, should I only be using firebase admin SDK?

Comment: Yes, you should use the firebase admin SDK in a nextjs server component or an api route.

Comment: Also where can I find firestore-admin documentation like this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_? I can't seem to find the admin equivalent of this documentation...

Comment: The firebase-admin/firestore documentation can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.firestore) .

Comment: Thanks! So there's no documentation on the specific functions like `getDoc` etc? I'm mostly guessing based on this https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#delete and it's a bit annoying that it seems that I need to revert back to a different style than using the current client SDK, i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73888413/firestore-using-firebase-client-sdk-v9-modular-with-admin-privileges? Am I doing the right thing?